# Как получить доступ к private полю используя рефлексию?

Tags: c#

Помогите разобраться, есть следующий код

```
public class MyFieldClass
{
    private Dictionary<int, string> test = new Dictionary<int, string>
    {
        [1] = "Один",
        [2] = "Два",
        [3] = "Три"
    };
}

public class MyFieldInfoClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        Type myType = typeof(MyFieldClass);
        FieldInfo myFieldInfo1 = myType.GetField("test", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        var test2 = myFieldInfo1.GetValue(null);
    }
}
```

как можно получить длину `private` словаря `test` в классе `MyFieldClass`?

Comment: Ну, т.к. поле нестатическое, вы должны иметь экземпляр класса, для того чтобы достать значение. Этот экземпляр надо передать в GetValue вместо null. Ну а далее просто приводите полученное значение к словарю и используете нужные его свойства

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К полю объекта можно получить доступ только через экземпляр этого объекта.

```cs
var obj = new MyFieldClass();
Type myType = typeof(MyFieldClass);
FieldInfo myFieldInfo1 = myType.GetField("test", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

var test2 = myFieldInfo1.GetValue(obj);
```

`null` покатит только для `static` поля, конечно если убрать при этом `BindingFlags.Instance`.